DuckDB constructing a full GeoJSON feature collection
What I've done:

I'm using the nodeJS DuckDB client
I've loaded the spatial extension and JSON extension
I've read a parquet file with a WKB geometry column into duckDB
I want to perform a query on all of my data. I then want to return back the query results as GeoJSON (right now I'm using a LIMIT for debugging purposes)
The documentation for St_AsGeoJSON states "This does not return a complete GeoJSON document, only the geometry fragment. To construct a complete GeoJSON document or feature, look into using the DuckDB JSON extension in conjunction with this function." I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that

Code:
const db = await Database.create(":memory:");
await db.run(`INSTALL spatial; LOAD spatial`);
await db.run(`INSTALL json; LOAD json`);
await db.run(`
        CREATE TABLE duckdata AS 
        SELECT * EXCLUDE ${wkbColName}, ST_GeomFromWKB(${wkbColName}) AS geometry
        FROM read_parquet('${fileName}/*.parquet', hive_partitioning = true)`
      );

 const con = await db.connect();
 let rows = await con.all(`
      COPY (SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) AS geometry FROM duckdata LIMIT 10) TO 'my.json' (ARRAY true)`
 );

What I'm currently getting back as output (only showing two rows for simplicity sake):
[
    {"geometry":
        {"type":"Point",
         "coordinates":[-73.79132080078125,40.64582824707031]}
    },
    {"geometry":
        {"type":"Point",
         "coordinates":[-73.79132080078125,40.64582824707031]}
    },
]

What I'd like to get back as output:

I'd like to get back an array of dictionary object keys (I don't want to write to .json file) and I'd like to set another json dictionary to include column attributes that looks something like this:

[
       {"type" : "Feature", 
        "properties" : {  
            "capacity" : "10", 
            "type" : "U-Rack",
            "mount" : "Surface"
        }, 
        "geometry" : { 
            "type" : "Point", 
            "coordinates" : [ -71.073283, 42.417500 ] 
        }
},
       {"type" : "Feature", 
        "properties" : {  
            "capacity" : "10", 
            "type" : "U-Rack",
            "mount" : "Surface"
        }, 
        "geometry" : { 
            "type" : "Point", 
            "coordinates" : [ -71.073283, 42.417500 ] 
        }
},
]

What I've tried:
 let rows = await con.all(`
      COPY (SELECT * EXCLUDE geometry AS properties, ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) AS geometry FROM duckdata LIMIT 10) TO 'my.json' (ARRAY true)`
    );


I get an error Duplicate struct entry name "properties". No matter what I change the name of properties too I still get this error
I can't figure out how to return the values as an array and not as .json file

I've also tried this:
 let rows = await con.all(`
      COPY (
        SELECT 
          json_object(
            'type', 'Feature', 
            'properties', json_object(
               'vendorId', VendorID
            ),
            'geometry', ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry)
          ) 
          FROM duckdata 
          LIMIT 10 
      ) TO 'my.json' (ARRAY true)`
    );

with the output of:
[
    {"json_object('type', 'Feature', 'properties', json_object('vendorId', VendorID), 'geometry', st_asgeojson(geometry))":{"type":"Feature","properties":{"vendorId":"2"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.79132080078125,40.64582824707031]}}},
    {"json_object('type', 'Feature', 'properties', json_object('vendorId', VendorID), 'geometry', st_asgeojson(geometry))":{"type":"Feature","properties":{"vendorId":"1"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.99661254882812,40.766761779785156]}}},
]


another option is I could just return all the data as an array and then use a for loop to build a geojson object from the data but this would take much longer and I want to utilize the performance boost that duckdb offers with SQL


If anyone finds this from google I couldn't figure out how to write SQL code to get the full geojson document. What I ended up doing was something like this:
CREATE TABLE mytable AS 
SELECT 
    * EXCLUDE WKBColumn, 
    ST_GeomFromWKB(WKBColumn) AS geometry
FROM 
    read_parquet('${sourceConfig.fileName}/*.parquet', hive_partitioning = true);

This reads a parquet from disk and converts the WKB buffer column to a GEOMETRY duckdb type
SELECT 
    * EXCLUDE geometry, 
    ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) AS geometry 
FROM 
    mytable 

I select all my columns but exclude the geometry column and then convert it to a geojson object.
Then I wrote some js code to translate the array of dictionaries I get back from the query to a full geojson document. This was actually quite fast and didn't take as long as I thought even on larger queries. You'll notice that there are some hardcoded things that need to be improved but this will get you started in the right direction if you run into this problem that I did
const metadata = config.properties || {};
const columns = Object.keys(data[0]);

return {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: data.map((row) =>
    formatFeature(row, columns, metadata.idField)
  ),
  properties: metadata,
};
  

function formatFeature(values, columns, idField) {
  let feature = {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {},
    geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [],
    },
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    const value = values[columns[i]];

    if (columns[i] === "geometry") {
      let geom = values[columns[i]]
      var geometry = JSON.parse(geom);
      feature.geometry = geometry;
    } else {
      if (columns[i] == idField) {
        feature["id"] = value.toString();
      }
      feature.properties[columns[i]] = value;
    }
  }

  return feature;
}

more info here too https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb_spatial/issues/370
